# Testmail package download

Tags: email, email-integration

I would need some RFC compliant emails to test some email related scripts and software and I am to lazy to create them myself as there are a lot of combinations/cases.

This problem surely is not new so I guess I can find a package of test emails somewhere?

Or maybe there is some sort of software to create mails for that purpose? (yes, I know mailclients.. you know what I mean :)